# Where is Garbage Collection in Xcode Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, garbage-collection

As I know , Garbage collection is not enabled by default in Cocoa and should be selected in Build setting. But in build setting I just can see automatic reference counting. What am I missing?[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple have deprecated Garbage Collection. You should use ARC instead. You can find ARC documentation [here](//developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i). There is a WWDC talk about ARC [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323)

When you use ARC, objects are reference counted rather than garbage collected. However you are not expected to call `retain` or `release`/`autorelease`. The compiler inserts calls to `retain` or `release`/`autorelease` on your behalf. In practice, this works similarly to garbage collection. You must be careful to avoid reference cycles which can prevent the reference count of objects becoming zero and preventing the objects from being dealloced. This mostly is introduced by parent/child relationships when a child holds a reference to it's parent as happens in most instances involving delegates.

Reference cycles can be avoided by marking one of the references in the parent/child relationship as weak. Properties marked as weak create a weak reference to an object. Weak references to an object are set to `nil` when the reference count of an object becomes zero.

The talk I mentioned [above](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=323) goes into further details.

Comment: Thanks.  I have never used ARC before. Is it really like GC ( I mean I don't need be so careful about memory management as in GC ?). On the other hand some pre-configured features as dealloc are not supported in ARC. What should I do for my previously written codes including dealloc and so on?